# MVC3 - Having trouble passing int[] to controller action on RedicrectToAction from a different action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 actions within the same controller.

```
public ActionResult Index(string filter, int[] checkedRecords)
```

and

```
public ActionResult ExportChkedCSV(string filter, int[] checkedRecords)
```

The second Action (ExportChkedCSV) contains this redirect:

```
if (reject != 0)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { filter, checkedRecords });
        }
```

When I step through, the parameter checkedRecords is populated correctly on the RedirectToAction statement, but when it hits the Index ActionResult from there, checkedRecords is null.  I've tried doing filter =, checkedRecords =, etc.  I am having no problem with this from View to Controller.  If I change the array type to anything else, I can grab the value - how do I pass int[] from action to action?  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't send complex types as redirect parameters in MVC, only primitive types like numerics and strings

Use TempData to pass the array

```
...
if (reject != 0) {
    TempData["CheckedRecords"] = yourArray;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { filter = filterValue });
}
...

public ActionResult Index(string filter) {
    int[] newArrayVariable;
    if(TempData["CheckedRecords"] != null) {
        newArrayVariable = (int[])TempData["CheckedRecords"];
    }
    //rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. Since you are essentially passing around GET parameters, how exactly would that fit with a complex type like an Array? I +1 this answer because you can use the TempData dictionary to pass around the values. Note that the data is only available for one request and after that it disappears.

Comment: It is correct, when you think about it, you're asking to render a view with new parameters.. you can't build a URL with an array. And yes, 1 action + 1 is all it's good for so if the redirected action needed to redirect again, it would have to be recreated and sent again

Comment: This works perfectly and explains why what I was trying does not - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are sending two null values. When you use new {} you are making a new object. You have to not only define the index names, but the values as well.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { filter = filter, checkedRecords = checkedRecords });
```

Comment: Thank you for your trying to help, however this is not the issue.  I tried this (please see original post) but it makes no difference.  The string filter works perfectly and is received by Index (as is).   I am doing this in several other places successfully without the additional definition. I tried it again for good measure (same null result).  I swap out the int[] type with int and send a value and it works fine, but I need to send int[].THanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that ASP.Net knows how to build a URL using the int array you're passing. If the int array uniquely identifies a resource then you could try converting the array into a hyphen-delimited (or similar) string and then parsing the string within the Index method.

If you're just trying to persist data between requests, use TempData:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata.aspx